# Search for a String in excel and read a column value in that row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to Python, I am new to coding basically. I started with a small project, where I have to clean up some unwanted rows from Excel files.

I have a folder 'Data' containing some 'N' number of files. An excel contains the details of all these file like: Name, age, todelete, country of each file from folder 'Data'.
I want to search each file name in that excel, and extract that todelete column value and delete those many rows in each file in Data folder

Here is what I tried:

```
files = '\\Data'
epath = '\\details.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(epath)
sheet =   workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(files, '*.xls')):
    name = ntpath.basename(filename)
    search = name[: -4]
    for row in sheet:
        if search in row[0]:
        valuetodelete = row[2]
 with open(filename) as D
   df = pd.DataFrame(D)
    df.drop(df.index[[0,valuetodelete]]
```

Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: How is this not working exactly?

Comment: I am failing to fetch the rowid, I want to search a file name in 1st column,  for each file name i want the value from 2nd column in that row. please guide me regarding it.